# Internal meta-analysis on unbalanced between groups design with and without a covariate

Tags: meta-analysis

I have decided to do an internal meta-analysis to estimate cumulative effect of Factor X across a set of three studies. Although all three studies are between-subject, they are quite complex. I have carried out 2x2 (one of them is Factor X of interest) ANOVAs for two of the studies and a three-way 2x2x2 (one of them is Factor X of interest) ANCOVA with one covariate for the third study. But really we are interested in one specific set of main effects across all three studies. The main effect of interest is significant in the first two studies and it is non-significant in the third study (and specifically, after we introduce a covariate that needs to be included).

Following Laken's 2013 article in Frontiers, I understood that ideally I would use partial omega squared estimates to compare effect sizes between the three studies (although, I have wondered whether I can do it with unbalanced designs) or at generalized partial eta squared (as per Olejnik & Algina, 2003). Both of these are fairly easy to run in R with readily available functions.

And this is where I got stuck. Meta-analyses packages support analyses with r or d  effects and even these need conversions to more standardised solutions. My instinct is that it would be easier to convert to r since eta-square belongs to r-family. Here are some solutions I have considered:
-> Using raw scores of outcome measures across two groups of interest - however, I cannot really do it if I want to account for the covariate in the last study. I want to be able to evidence that the overall effect is there even after accounting for the covariate in the third study. This leaves me with F-value solutions.
-> I have tried to find calculators converting either omega squared to r or generalized partial eta squared to r, but I did not succeed.

I have three questions:
(1) And importantly, can I even compare these effects?
(2) How?
(3) If meta-analysis is not possible, what other cumulative effects I can consider? I don't want to end up in a situation when it is more convenient to drop one study because the effect is not as hypothesised - we know that the probability of concluding that a true effect is significant in 3/3 studies is considerably lower than finding it in 2/3 studies. I want to be able to convince reviewers (and myself) that even though the effect in one of the studies is non-significant, the overall effect is still worth considering when we consider all three studies together.

Thank you in advance!